# AHK Window Control - Resize: What determines the +12px maximum window size past screen bounds, and can it be circumvented?

Tags: windows-10, display, autohotkey, window

Exactly as the title says, my question is: what determines the +12px limit (past screen bounds) for maximum window sizing?  And can this be circumvented to increase window size to any arbitrary size exceeding the screen bounds +12px?